# Testing REST - submitting a web-form. Identifying why the server responses with 500 for some emails and for some - 200

Tags: manual-testing, rest, postman, http

The troubled email is teststudent12@skyeng.ru, the URL is https://junior.skyeng.ru/online-uroki-po-matematike/ (form is placed almost at footer).

The website to test is in Russian. If you want to help me - please translate it in Chrome, it's easy. 
Or you just go directly to Postman:

```
POST https://crm.skyeng.ru/order/createV2Kid
Body(x-www-form-urlencoded):
parentName: test
parentEmail: teststudent12@skyeng.ru
parentPhone: +79650389823 (any decent Russian mobile phone)
subject: mathematics
childName: test
```

So the response is 500 Internal Server Error. The task here is to localize the error. To find out the specific conditions why the bug occurs.

What I've done (just some of examples):

```
teststudent@skyeng.ru
x-www-form-urlencoded
200 ok

teststudentnew@skyeng.ru
x-www-form-urlencoded
500

7qa@pm.me
x-www-form-urlencoded
200

teststudent1@skyeng.ru
x-www-form-urlencoded
500
```

And if you change from x-www-form-urlencoded to form-data it will return every request with 200 OK, even with our email teststudent12@skyeng.ru.

So my questions are:

- Is it really happening because of x-www-form-urlencoded? If so, why then we are able to get 200 Ok with teststudent@skyeng.ru and any other real email?
- Maybe we should look at some Headers or other additional information and if yes - where exactly?

I can't even google anything because I don't know exactly what to find. I googled articles about form-data/x-www-form-urlencoded, HTTP (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP) and still can't localize the bug.

I would appreciate any help!

Comment: Do you have access to server logs?

Comment: @dzieciou Hi. No I don't have an access to server logs. I applied for a job and they gave me this test-assignment: "All you know that it is impossible to send a form with email teststudent12@skyeng.ru. Why? You need to localize the bug, workaround".

Comment: Probably when you send urlenconded properties which are longer than some given size the issue appears? for example `teststudent@skyeng.ru` is okay but `test_student@skyeng.ru` is not okay

Comment: @wec test_student@skyeng.ru returns 500. I just registered a new real email account on Yandex (Russian mail provider) - teststudent12@yandex.ru, tried it and it returned 200. So it has the exact length, amount of characters and digits like teststudent12@skyeng.ru

Comment: Perhaps this email is already registered. So register ing same email twice can help. Or check for this email is hardcodedby the authors of this home work.

Comment: Isn't that cheating if we are solving the problem that has to confirm your skills for the job? How is that different from doing the assigment at the university for some one else?

Comment: Re: "The task here is to localize the error. To find out the specific conditions why the bug occurs." Why or when?

Comment: I'm not asking you to give me the explicit answer which I copy-paste to the employer. I'm just asking for help where to dig. How else should I learn? Imagine that you work for the company for a year, then they gave you the task and you have no clue how to do it. Your actions? Should you retire or jump from the bridge or what? No, you have ask the community for help. And it is not cheating. The task says "to determine specific conditions why the bug occurs".

Comment: Having played around with this for just a bit, I think you might find more problems (or at least questions that would need answers) than just one bug. So in addition to trying to localize this particular bug, you might create a list of (potential) problems and e.g. how you found out (why you took a path that led to such and such problem). Showing how you think about problems and showing you are able to find more problems should be both higly valuable.

Answer (score 2):

Your testing is good.  You are considering different possibilities and conducting experiments to see what happens.  That is great.

I would continue that process.  Here are some thoughts for you to try out.  They are not answers you can copy and paste (which, as you indicate is good), they are ideas for your to try out yourself.  Good luck!

- Try special characters, numbers and letters, underscores 'as is'
- Try special character that *are* encoded, e.g. `&nbsp` for space
- Try different input lengths
- Use an email that was created today
- Use an email that you know doesn't exist
- Use an accepted email then try a second time with same email and record error
- Timing - try quick and slow data entry
- Javascript - try disabling javascript
- Browser errors - see chrome console for any errors, such as network

In some of the above cases, the details of the error may help point you towards the cause

Comment: +1 for mentioning the importance of the process itself. I think in such exercises during the hiring process, that might be even more important than the actual answer.

Answer (score 1):

-

> Is it really happening because of x-www-form-urlencoded? If so, why
>   then we are able to get 200 Ok with teststudent@skyeng.ru and any
>   other real email?

it seems that it's a bug with the way the url encoded data is being decoded in your test product. For example consider the below comment 
 https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/18261#issuecomment-331050300

Here , + sign in url encoded values are being replaced .

I think something similar is happening in test product where numbers are not decoded as expected.

The server should handle both content type the same way.

https://dev.to/getd/x-www-form-urlencoded-or-form-data-explained-in-2-mins-5hk6

> Maybe we should look at some Headers or other additional information
>   and if yes - where exactly?

About headers and content type , you should ask for the API contract . Which is just a documentation stating what all headers, what body, what methods a API endpoint supports and what response it gives for different scenarios.

Usually a swagger page is setup for this purpose instead of paper documentation

> I can't even google anything because I don't know exactly what to
>   find. I googled articles about form-data/x-www-form-urlencoded, HTTP
>   (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP) and still can't
>   localize the bug.

Try different boundary value, and partition scenarios like character length , numbers , special characters , different encodings , etc

Eg: try giving exact char plus a digit , if error comes then just give digit . Then we can confirm that the error is due to the wrong decoding of number by the system

Comment: Please provide a comment when downvoting so that others knows why this is wrong or correct the person who down voted it

Answer (score 0):

It might be variety of things.

Return message only shows in payload `internal server error` so you need to check internally, on the server what happened. 80% of this type of bugs is something in DB (bad constraints on the tables).

Then only way to know for sure is to see what backend is doing and without code or access to proper logs it's impossible.